# How to set environment variable within the docker file?

Tags: docker, python

The `CMD` of my dockerfile is this: `["python", "myproject/start_slide_server.py"]`

However for this to work, I need to set the `PYTHONPATH` to `/app`, which is the parent directory of `myproject`

If I start the docker process and override `CMD` with `bash`, I can run the following

```
root@42e8998a8ff7:/app# export PYTHONPATH=.
root@42e8998a8ff7:/app# python myproject/start_slide_server.py
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8090/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 236-035-556
```

And it works as expected

Now I add the line

```
RUN export PYTHONPATH=/app
```

before

```
CMD ["python" , "myproject/start_slide_server.py"]
```

it just failed

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/myproject/start_slide_server.py", line 23, in <module>
    from myproject import env
ImportError: No module named myproject
```

It seems like the `RUN` line does not have any impact at all

I really do not want to define `ENV` at the `docker`command level because this `PYTHONPATH` will not change from one image to next.

How can I achieve this?

---

I can use the `ENV` directive

```
ENV PYTHONPATH /app
```

Comment: What was your outcome using the ENV directive?

Answer (score 6):

You should not over-write the `PYTHONPATH` with your path but append it; otherwise the system will not find the installed Python packages.

- Option 1: `RUN export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/app"`
- Option 2: `ENV PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/app"`